Asynchronus calls to get Bluetooth & Location Permission
I'm a newbie to Flutter & am trying to get a simple functionality in my app where I want to check if the users Bluetooth & location are enabled before beginning any ops however I'm getting inconsistent results and black screens in the process, can someone explain in what I'm missing here -

  void findBleState() async {
    var locationStatus = await Permission.location.status;
    if (locationStatus.isDenied) {
      await Permission.location.request();
    }
    var locationServiceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!locationServiceEnabled) {
      await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
    }

    FlutterBluePlus.adapterState.listen((BluetoothAdapterState state) async {
      if (state == BluetoothAdapterState.on && locationStatus.isGranted && locationServiceEnabled) {
        print('Bluetooth is active');
        print('Scanning Status - ${FlutterBluePlus.isScanningNow}');
        startScan();
        scanedDevices();
      } else if (state == BluetoothAdapterState.off) {
        await _handleBluetoothOff(locationServiceEnabled);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> _handleBluetoothOff(bool locationServiceEnabled) async {
    print('Bluetooth & location is not active');
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      try {
        await FlutterBluePlus.turnOn();
        print('Bluetooth & location turned on');
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error turning on Bluetooth: $e');
      }
      print('Bluetooth is now turned on!');
    }
  }

When both Bluetooth & Location are disabled it tends to behave in an unpredictable manner where it at times prompts bluetooth permission and gets stuck or gets stuck on a blackscreen without any prompts.
Thanks in advance.

check for location permission https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#faq

You should try to ensure the correct permissions are specified in AndroidManifest.xml file.
Something like this
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

